# Parallel Quicksort in Python

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, quicksort

I would like to implement the Parallel Quicksort in Python. 
I know Quicksort, you have to choose a pivot, partition, but how do spawned them as independent task in Python?

Here is the pseudocode for it:

```
QS(A[1:n])
if n=1 then return A[1]
pivot <--any value from A (random)
L <- A[A[:] < pivot]
R <- A[A[:] > pivot]
A(L) <- spawn QS(L)
A(R) <- QS(R)
sync
return A(L) ++ A(R)
```

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do it, but it's unlikely to speed up your code. You can use `ThreadPoolExecutor` to create a thread and get result back from it. Here is a simple illustration with a function that sums an array:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
pool = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)
def add(arr):
    if len(arr)<2:
        return sum(arr)  #cheating a little
    mid = len(arr)//2
    f = pool.submit(add,arr[:mid])
    y = add(arr[mid:])
    return y+f.result()
```

`submit()` takes a function's name as first argument and then takes the function's arguments. So for your code it'll be something like `f = pool.submit(QS,L)`.

Please remember though Python supports concurrency but not parallelism using thread. Take a look [here](https://hackernoon.com/concurrent-programming-in-python-is-not-what-you-think-it-is-b6439c3f3e6a) for their difference. So above code will actually run in single thread. Now you can use `ProcessPoolExecutor` for process parallelism, which python supports well. But the overhead in data IO will probably eat up any speed up you gain from process parallelism.